# How do I use Jekyll in a subdirectory?

Tags: http, jekyll

Jekyll assumes that the generated site will be served from the root directory, and subsequently all of the links are absolute beginning with "/". I'd like to serve out a blog from a subdirectory, i.e., `http://www.example.com/~user/blog`.

Setting `permalink` variable (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) would be a partial fix, but doesn't address other things such as css files.

I'll be glad for any pointers.

Comment: Can you please post your solution?

Answer (score 10):

You want to use the **baseurl** config option in your _config.yml file. Permalinks will then be relative to that. See the Jekyll docs for the **baseurl** option:
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Assuming you are using at least Jekyll 1.0.0.