# Deploying jekyll to a subdirectory

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Hi i'm trying to deploy jekyll to a subdirectory 2 levels deep on my server, `/dev/more`

Tried following [this](http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2013/03/02/Running-Your-Jekyll-Blog-from-a-Subdirectory.html) link, but all my css links and hyperlinks keeps referring to my root folder `public_html` instead of the `/dev/more` folder.

I'm trying to deploy jekyll's stock blog out of the box. uploaded the `_site` folder to the `/dev/more` folder on my server

I can fix my css and js calls by using 
`<link href="./css/syntax.css">`
instead of
`<link href="/css/syntax.css">`
but not the generated jekyll links to my posts.

I'm guessing i either have to do something on my _config.yml or on my .htaccess, so far i've had no luck.

This issue has been asked [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635665/how-do-i-deploy-jekyll-to-a-subdirectory) without any answers

Comment: Figured out it comes down to making jekyll generate `css/syntax.css` instead of `/css/syntax.css`, the trailing `/` makes apache refer to the `public_html` parent folder. Either that or have .htaccess establish `dev/more` as the home folder somehow

Answer (score 1):

When you have this (absolute) path:

`/foo/index.html`

You're saying, "Take me to the file `index.html` in the directory `foo` found **in the root directory**", aka the folder where Apache/Ngios/Python/PHP/whatever is serving the content from.

This relative path:

`foo/index.html`

Is saying, "Take me to the file `index.html` in the directory `foo` found in the directory **I'm currently in**."

Comment: In other words, `/foo/index.html` is not a relative path, it is an absolute path.

Comment: yes, but still i dont know how to generate relative paths. setting `relative_permalinks: true` or `false` doesnt seem to make any difference

Comment: Have you set the baseurl? And if you're uploading the _site folder then your URLs won't change unless you rerun Jekyll on the folder or run Jekyll on your server.