# Jekyll on GitHub Pages: permalinks don't include baseurl

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, permalinks

I'm working through [a guide](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/) for setting up Jekyll on GitHub Pages. My GitHub repo publishes to `~.github.io/hello-pages`, so naturally I'm plugging `{{ site.baseurl }}` into anchor tags, etc. That's working great.

What isn't working is permalinks: I have to manually spell out `permalink: /hello-pages/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title.html` in `_config.yml` for any of the permalinks to work; otherwise they link to e.g. `~.github.io/blog/x/y/z` instead of `~.github.io/hello-pages/blog/x/y/z` like I expect.

Manually specifying `baseurl: /hello-pages` has no effect (I suppose GitHub's Jekyll config already does that).

Manually typing "/hello-pages" anywhere seems like quite a rigid design that I'd like to avoid. [An older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638250/3063273) says that permalinks should "just work". What gives?

---

**Edit**

I am constructing the broken URLs like this:

`<a href="{{ post.url }}">`

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong. I need to do one of the below things. Here is documentation about this: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters

#### `<a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">`

This turns the URL into a relative URL, taking the base URL into account.

#### `<a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">`

Same as the above, but makes absolute URLs.

#### `<a href="{{ post.url | prepend:site.baseurl }}">`

Prepends the base URL to the permalink.